# Is it possible to interact with inner hologram when 2 holograms are nested in hololens (MRTK in Unity)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I am using MRTK in unity for hololens development. My requirement involves having a hologram inside another hologram. I wanted to clarify whether it is possible to interact with the inner hologram in this scenario using the hololens gestures. When I try to use the pinch gesture to move the hologram it only moves the outer hologram. Is it possible out of the box or by extending the gesture in any way. Thank you for any pointers.

Comment: If it is not necessary for you to interact with the outer hologram at all, you could try to remove the collider (Sphere Collider / Box Collider ...) from the hologram and see if this is what you want to achieve.

Comment: Would maybe this help you [How to select the inner gameobject when an object is inside another in hololens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67103999/how-to-select-the-inner-gameobject-when-an-object-is-inside-another-in-hololens) .. this is will allow interaction with all objects but always prefer the most inner one first assuming it is a child of the outer one